# Images not showing in admin panel as well as no log out option is there.

Tags: magento2

After completion of Magento 2 Community Edition , Images not showing in admin panel as well as  no log out option is there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to regenerate static content files and clear cache. All commands assume that your current folder is magento root folder. Enter the following command:

Regenerate static files:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Clean and flush cache:

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Thanks for for your reply.. could you please guide me where to run these commands ..I am new to this technology.

Comment: you need to access your webserver via console. if you are using linux - login to server via ssh console. if you are using windows - just run "cmd" to open command console. after that move to magento server and run commands